# Clearing the actual log file after archiving using RollingAppender in logback.xml instead of appending

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, rollingfileappender

I am having the below configuration in logback.xml file. The log file is getting archived daily.

I wanted to clear the parent log file(app.log), after the log file has been archived. So that the app.log file does not become too big to manage.Is there any way in do this using logback.xml configuration. With the below configurations, every-day log file is getting archived(and the content of the files is on a daily basics).But the actual log file has the from the start of the application and is growing in size.

I am looking for a configuration, when after archiving the logs files, the actual log file is also cleared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration> 
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="/var/log/application" />   
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -
                %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}/app.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}/archived/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>        
    </appender>     
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.demo" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Are there any tags or configuration to specify to clear the parent log file after rolling.Now even after clearing the achieved logs, parent log file(app.log).

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: I am still looking for a valid suggestion for this. Any help/suggestion will be appreciated